# WM_NCHITTEST: Sizing Commands Not Working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, borderless

I have a custom borderless window, and I want to be able to resize it.  I have a code that tests for a virtual border, to grab and resize.  It worked with Windows 7.  But, for some reason, it does not work with Windows 10.  Here is the code in `WM_NCHITTEST`:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
 {
     bool  bLeft = 0, bRight = 0, bTop = 0, bBottom = 0;
     bool bHorz =0, bVert =0;
     RECT rMenu;

     GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rWnd);

     if (LOWORD(lParam) > rWnd.left && LOWORD(lParam) < rWnd.left+4)      bLeft = 1;
     if (LOWORD(lParam) > rWnd.right-4 && LOWORD(lParam) < rWnd.right)    bRight = 1;
     if (HIWORD(lParam) > rWnd.top && HIWORD(lParam) < rWnd.top+4)        bTop = 1;
     if (HIWORD(lParam) > rWnd.bottom-4 && HIWORD(lParam) < rWnd.bottom)  bBottom = 1;

     if (bLeft && bTop)      return HTTOPLEFT;
     if (bRight && bTop)     return HTTOPRIGHT;
     if (bLeft && bBottom)   return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
     if (bRight && bBottom)  return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

     if (bLeft)    return HTLEFT;
     if (bRight)   return HTRIGHT;
     if (bTop)     return HTTOP;
     if (bBottom)  return HTBOTTOM;

     GetMenuItemRect(hWnd, hMenu, NUMMI, &rMenu);
     if (LOWORD(lParam)>rMenu.right && LOWORD(lParam)<rWnd.right-100)              bHorz = 1;
     if (HIWORD(lParam)>rWnd.top+WFRAME && HIWORD(lParam)<rWnd.top+WFRAME+cyMenu)  bVert = 1;
     if (bHorz && bVert)  return HTCAPTION;

     auto nchResult = DefWindowProc(hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, wParam, lParam);
     return nchResult;
 }
```

As I mentioned, this worked great with Win7.  But, it somehow doesn't work with Win10.  I should also note that the final section, the one returning `HTCAPTION`, *does* work.  In fact, I can replace any of the sizing commands, `HTLEFT`, `HTTOP`, etc, with `HTCAPTION`, and drag the window around by that border.  So, I know that the border testing is accurate.  However, none of the sizing commands work.  I do not get the double-arrow cursor.  Nor, can I drag that border to resize the window.

Comment: `none of the sizing commands work.` It works for me. See the [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHLbi.gif). My windows version is Windows 10 1903.

Comment: Thanks Strive Sun.  For me, the problem arose when I disabled the `WS_THICKFRAME` style.  That disabled all sizing-border functionality.  I had to do this, because Windows 10 leaves an ugly white band at the top of the page, which cannot be covered by `WM_NCPAINT`.  If you change your background color, you will see what I mean.  Luckily, I found a better starting point for a custom window, which I noted in this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518580/borderless-window-covers-taskbar/64529205?noredirect=1#comment114103883_64529205)

Comment: Do you need to draw menu items in a borderless window? I noticed that if the non-client area is removed, no white band will appear.

Comment: Yes, everything needs to be drawn, including the menu bar.  A menu resource can still be used.  Buttons can be used to simulate menubar items (unless someone has a better solution).  Use `GetSubMenu()` and `TrackPopupMenu()` to display the drop-down menus.  Handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` message to create virtual sizing borders, and an area to grab and drag the window.

Comment: OK. It seems that all of your problems have been solved well.  Please continue to enjoy your trip:)