# Borderless Window Covers Taskbar

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, borderless

I have a custom-made borderless window.  When maximized, it covers the taskbar.  This is not what I want.  I have played with the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message.  But, I have found that Windows 10 will then leave an extra 8-pixel gap along both the bottom and right side.  It is an all-or-nothing proposition.  Here is the first code that I tried:

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
     PMINMAXINFO pmm;
     pmm = (PMINMAXINFO)lParam;
     pmm->ptMaxSize.x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
     pmm->ptMaxSize.y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
     return 0;
```

The result of this is *identical* to what I had, without hooking the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message.  So, I knocked two pixels off of the bottom, so I could access the taskbar (which is in "autohide" mode":

```
case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
     PMINMAXINFO pmm;
     pmm = (PMINMAXINFO)lParam;
     pmm->ptMaxSize.x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
     pmm->ptMaxSize.y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-2;
     return 0;
```

Suddenly, I have a *10-pixel* gap on the bottom, and a *new* 8-pixel gap on the right side!  this appears to be a Windows 10 thing, as this never happened with Win7.  I have also tried `SystemParametersInfo`, calling `SPI_GETWORKAREA` (instead of `GetSystemMetrics()`).  This yields the same results.

From what I gather, the problem is *not* with `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`.  Instead, I need to put a command into my code, to keep the taskbar on top.  I have searched through the windows styles.  But, I have found nothing of help there.

Does anyone know how to fix this critical problem.

Comment: How about handling [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-windowposchanging) and adjusting the window size there?  The documentation behind the link tells you how.

Comment: Maybe take a look at GLFW. It's a very nice window abstraction library that should probably handles this type of problem (https://github.com/glfw/glfw)

Comment: Windows adds an invisible border around non-maximized windows. You can get the size of this border using `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with the `DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer in a most unlikely place.  Someone was trying to manipulate borders with Python code.  From their attempt, I was able to devise a solution for a borderless window, in C++.  Here is the result:

To start, I created a window with the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE` style, to enable all Windows functions.  I then handled the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message with this code:

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
 {
    WINDOWPLACEMENT      wp;
    LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS  szr;

    wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
    GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &wp);
    szr = LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS(lParam);
    if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED)  szr->rgrc[0].bottom -= (WFRAME+2);
    return 0;
 }
```

In the code above, I subtracted the width of the border from the bottom of the first rectangle.  The extra 2 pixels were added, to expose the bit of the auto-hidden taskbar.  The maximized window now acts as it should, allowing access to the taskbar.

To create my virtual client area in this borderless window, I added this bit of code to both the `WM_CREATE` and `WM_SIZE` handlers:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT  wp;
GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rWnd);
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rClient);
wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &wp);
rClient.left += WFRAME;  rClient.right -= WFRAME;    rClient.top += (WFRAME+cyMenu);
if (wp.showCmd == SW_SHOWNORMAL)  rClient.bottom -= WFRAME;
cxClient = rClient.right-rClient.left;
cyClient = rClient.bottom-rClient.top;
```

The element `cyMenu` is a space reserved for my virtual menu bar.  It will contain a series of buttons, simulating the menu and min/max/close buttons.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Yes, I will mark it as an answer.  Unfortunately, when I answer one of my own questions, this site will not allow me to mark it as an "Answer", until after 24 hours.

Comment: You can get a monitor's dimensions: total and work space. You are looking for work space dimensions.